# Angular 6 How to pass array in one component to other

Tags: angular

I want to get data from textboxes and show them in table. But the textboxes are in other component and table is in the other component means table is children, so how can we pass data from textboxes to table?

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this a parent-child relationship between two components, you can create an `@Input` property in your Child Component and pass it from the Parent Component template:

Something like this:

Template of Parent Component:

```
<app-table
  *ngIf="data.length"
  [data]="data">
</app-table>
```

Child Component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class TableComponent {

  @Input() data: any[];

}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pass-table-data-to-input-property?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts) for your ref.